# How to set up apache2 to use with django?

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, python-3.4

I want to get access to my django site at leo.loc on my local machine.
But all what I did was in vain.

I'm using **ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.6, python 3.4, django 1.8 and virtualenv**.

I have the following in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/leo.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName leo.loc

<Directory "/home/siz/www/leo/leo/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /static /home/siz/www/leo/leo/static
<Directory /home/siz/www/leo/leo/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>



<Directory /home/siz/www/leo/leo/leo>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess leo python-path=/home/siz/www/leo/leo:/home/siz/www/leo/leo_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup leo
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/siz/www/leo/leo/leo/wsgi.py



</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: nothing, I get "This webpage is not available" in Chrome

Comment: What address are you accessing?

Comment: the address is leo.loc/

Comment: OK, and what have you done to map that address to your server? Have you edited your hosts file, for example?

Comment: I added it in /etc/hosts first time when I was setting up apache2 but then I deleted it(cause it was not in the tutorial to which I was following and I thought maybe it could be the problem), now I added it again  and corrected path. And now everything works, thanks.